# Can I override android:noHistory in code?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using an activity from a third-party library that has set android:noHistory to "true". Is it possible for me to override that value in code before I launch the activity?

Is there an opposite of "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY" flag I could use with the Intent?

Comment: Read it out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Comment: @VijaySinghChouhan That's the first link I checked but I couldn't find my answer. If you did find the answer in there, can you let me know so I can read it more carefully again?

Comment: None of which i am aware of . You can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` at runtime whever required and remove it from Manifest.  Intent has a method `#removeFlags`(from API 26) . but i never used it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using an activity from a third-party library that has set android:noHistory to "true".

Add an `<activity>` element to your own app's manifest, with an `android:name` attribute identifying the activity, and with `android:noHistory="false"`. As part of the manifest merger process, your app's `android:noHistory` value should override the library's `android:noHistory` value.

In general, overriding a library's manifest entry is a somewhat risky move, as you could break something that the library depends upon. In this particular case, it should be safe.

Comment: I also had to include the tools:replace="android:noHistory" attribute to my <activity> element for it to successfully merge. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may also be set with the noHistory attribute.

If set, onActivityResult() is never invoked when the current activity starts a new activity which sets a result and finishes.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Comment: A simple Copy and Paste . But this is not an answer .

Comment: Yup, copy/paste from doc. Because, author did not provide details info ;) So, now he can read about it.