# Start new activity and clear all activities except for the starting one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to start an activity called `ActivityA` and clear all the other activities that were launched in the same task. It can be done pretty easily using combination of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flags. The problem here is that I do not want to recreate `ActivityA` if it's already been started as the root of the task (I want to remove all of the other activities though). Consider this:

If I have A -> B -> C -> D, then I just want to close B, C and D and then return to A.

If I have B -> C -> A -> D, then I want to remove all of the activities and recreate activity A.

Is there a way to do so?

EDIT:
There's another important aspect I forgot to mention: `ActivityA` is can be used in multiple different apps, so there's no way I can do anything with B, C, D or any other activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
android:name=".B"
android:noHistory="true" />
```

Add android:noHistory="true" to your activities B, C, D. Now, when you press the back button, you will be returned to activity A

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot to mention that `ActivityA` is a part of a library, so unfortunately that's not an option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119387/can-i-override-androidnohistory-in-code Вроде можно это провернуть с активностью из библиотеки